# GORM: Encrypted Password for datasource

Tags: grails, grails-orm, jasypt

I am using grails 3.3.0 and GORM for my web application.

The DB password is encrypted and provided by Database team and placed in application.yml

```
dataSource:
    username: root
    password: ASDFASFCvcsdfaefsdsf!@#11
```

I am using jasypt plug-in for grails and able to decrypt the encrypted properties but by that time GORM has already initialized with encrypted password. How do I update or configure my GORM?

Do let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Try runtime.groovy to decrypt the pass when configuration is read. (placed in the same folder as application.groovy)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the dataSource.password property at `Application.groovy` before launch the context, something similar to:

```
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
   static void main(String[] args) {
      System.env['dataSource.password'] = 'unencripted'
      GrailsApp.run Application, args
   }
}
```